# Antonyms within a sentence Wordnet

Tags: python, wordnet

I have a corpus and am looking to find whether there is an antonymy relationship within each sentence, using Wordnet.

Does anyone have a clue whether looking for antonyms in Wordnet is at all possible? Thank you!

Comment: Wordnet seems to be unresponsive at the moment, so I can't check, but if it provides antonyms, it should be possible. If it only provides synonyms, then I don't think you can infer antonymic relationships solely from synonymic relationships.

Comment: Thank you! It does provide antonyms it seems. However I can hardly find any information concerning it.

Comment: Well, it's still unresponsive, so I can't really give any pointers. Frankly, if it's always this overloaded, you might be better off using another corpus - there ought to be something in [NLTK](http://nltk.org/) which would do the trick.

Comment: I agree, it's quite a challenge to do anything in Wordnet really... I'll go through the NLTK information again. :)

Comment: it seems like antonyms are done at a lemma level: https://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=98#hc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antonyms apply at a lemma level, not at a synset level. (According to [documentation](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html#lemmas) and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=98#hc1) in the nltk google code project.) Using an example from the latter link:

```
>>> wordnet.synset('light.a.01').antonyms()
[]
>>> wordnet.lemma('light.a.01.light').antonyms()
[Lemma('heavy.a.01.heavy')]
```